# How does the $L^\infty$ norm of the solution of $-\Delta u + \lambda u =0$, $\partial_\nu u=\alpha$ depend upon $\alpha$ and $\lambda$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $\lambda > 0$ be a constant and let $u$ be the weak solution on a bounded domain $\Omega$ of 
$$-\Delta u + \lambda u = 0 \quad\text{in $\Omega$}$$
$$\partial_\nu u = \alpha \quad \text{on $\partial\Omega$}$$
where $\partial_\nu u$ is the normal derivative and $\alpha > 0$ is a constant. Actually $u$ satisfies
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla \varphi + \lambda u\varphi = \int_{\partial\Omega} \alpha \varphi$$
for all $\varphi \in H^1(\Omega)$.

In fact $u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar \Omega)$ (see Salsa's book on PDEs in Action).

My question is, can $\lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$ bounded above by $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ in a simple explicit way (eg. maybe it's less than $\alpha$?)

---

The Salsa book gives
$$\lVert u \rVert_{\infty} \leq C(\lVert \alpha\rVert_{L^q}, \lambda, \Omega)$$
but is imprecise about this constant -- and the result may not be sharp since the RHS  depends on the $L^q$ norm of $\alpha$, but our $\alpha$ is much nicer than the general case.

Comment: What is assumed about $\partial\Omega$?

Comment: I was hoping Lipschitz, but smoother if necessary to get the result. @Andrew

Comment: Well, if $u\in H^2$, and the dimension is 3 or less, then $u\in L^\infty$ by Sobolev imbedding. So it seems like you answered your own question.

Comment: Yes, so I have changed the question

Comment: @ACA The problem in homogeneous so one can put $\alpha=1$.

Comment: By elliptic regularity, $u$ is smooth and you can use maximum principle arguments to obtain bounds. For example, if $\Omega$ is the unit disk, then you can show that $0 \leq u \leq \alpha(n/\lambda + 1/2)$. You need to subtract from $u$ a smooth function with normal derivative at least $\alpha$. Maybe a smoothed out distance function would work in general.